# Brownie compile does not use correct compiler version (VScode)

Tags: compiler, brownie

I'm having and issue with the "brownie compile" command.

I've copied and pasted [this contract from openzeppelin](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/erc20) following a youtube tutorial, I then right clicked on it to change the compiler version to 0.8.0 as in it's pragma but when I run the command brownie uses the 0.8.9 version and manualy changeing it from the settings doesn't work either, how can I tell brownie to use the correct version? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Can you copy the error message as text in the question?

Comment: Can you please not use screenshots? But instead copy paste the error message and all code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED(I'm using my newly made official account, I asked that question as a guest)

The problem was caused by me, I was importing older solidity contracts that were not on the 0.8.x version, I solved by importing an updated version of the contracts I was using